# Prove that if convex set A is scaled up then its polar is scaled down

Tags: solution-verification, convex-analysis

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ be a convex set, let $A^*$ be the polar set of $A$ and let $\lambda > 0$ where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. To show:

$(\lambda A)^* = \frac{1}{\lambda} A^*$

Let $x\cdot y$ be the scalar product for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R^n}$

Let $\lambda > 0$ be fixed. Let $y \in (\lambda A)^*$ then $ y \cdot (\lambda x) \, \leq 1$  $\forall x \in A$. But $ y \cdot (\lambda x) = (\lambda y) \cdot x \, \leq 1$ So by definition of polar set $A^*$, $\lambda y \in A^*$. Since $\lambda > 0$ then $y \in \frac{1}{\lambda} A^*$. So $(\lambda A)^* \subset \frac{1}{\lambda} A^*$ (1).

For the reverse inclusion, let $z \in A^*$ then $ z \cdot x  \leq 1 \,\,\forall x \in A$. Now $z \cdot x = \frac{1}{\lambda} z \cdot (\lambda x) \, \leq 1 \, \forall (\lambda x) \in \lambda A$. Then $\frac{1}{\lambda} z \in (\lambda A)^*$. Since $z \in A^*$ and $\lambda > 0$ we have that $\frac{1}{\lambda} z \in \frac{1}{\lambda} A^*$. So $ \frac{1}{\lambda} A^* \subset (\lambda A)^*$ (2).

From (1) and (2) above we have $(\lambda A)^* = \frac{1}{\lambda} A^*$.

The above is my attempt to prove this statement. Any comment on the above would be much appreciated.

Comment: Looks good. You do not need $A$ convex, and only $\lambda\ne 0$, not the full $\lambda > 0$.  In fact you can transform $A$ by an invertible linear transform $T$ then $(T A)^*= (T^t)^{-1}(A^*)$, with a similar proof.